# Issues loading audio source onto a component created with script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am trying to apply an audio source onto a game object upon destroying it.

I can add the Audio Source component fine with the script but i am unable to load the audio file onto it. 
The audio source component just says "None (Audio Clip)"

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BlockScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnMouseDown(){
        if(this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>() == null) {
            AudioSource blockBreakSound = this.gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            blockBreakSound.clip = Resources.Load("Assets/Sounds/BlockBreakingSound.wav") as AudioClip;
            blockBreakSound.Play();
            Destroy(this.gameObject, blockBreakSound.clip.length);
        } else {
            this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
            Destroy(this.gameObject, this.gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().clip.length);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not receiving any errors so i am having a hard time figuring out what the problem is.

I can apply the audio file manually onto the game object / prefab i am spawning, but as i am trying to optimize it somewhat i dont want hundreds of game object with the audio file on them to begin with but rather put them on the object upon trying to destroy them

Comment: Apparently, you have your WAV file in your RESOURCES. You load it with Resources.Load(). Is this the way how you are loading also other wav files?

Comment: [Documentation of Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) `The path is relative to any folder named **Resources** inside the Assets folder of your project`. You have to put the file in a `Resources` folder and call `Resources.Load("BlockBreakingSound")`

Comment: You're an angle! I had completely missed the fact that the actual file should be kept in a folder named Resources. 

I suppose thats what i get from reading a bit too fast through the documentation

Answer (score 0):

As @Hellium was really nice to point out i had missed the fact that i should keep my files in a folder called **Resources** to actually grab them with Resources.Load();

Thanks for the fast help :)